# width auto doesn't work on textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

`width:auto;` doesn't work on textarea, why ?

Screen of what I want : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p0ws.png)

DEMO : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/orb1uyrp/)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a width being applied via JS but to get your code to work as you want you could just add:

```
.newSujetText {
    margin-left: 115px; /* width of .userpost plus 10px padding */
    margin-right: 10px; /* add a bit of space from containers edge */
}
.newSujet {
    min-width: 100%; /* make textarea 100% of container */
    max-width: 100%; /* stop user from being able to make textarea bigger than container */
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/oyqLjjL1/

Sam.

Comment: Ok thats weird, unless I've miss understood you I've tested it on Mac in Firefox, Safari, Chrome & Windows IE 11 & 9

Comment: what browser are you using and what platform eg Windows 7 IE11

Comment: Windows 7 Firefox 40.0.2